# Secure a download link in Symfony 2

Tags: security, symfony, download

In my Symfony 2 project, I have a page displaying information about an entity. On this page there is also a link to a file associated to this entity.

The page is secured and it can be displayed only if the user as a specific role. The expected role is not the same for every entity so it's tested dynamicaly in the Action.

My problem is that even if the page is secured, anyone can access the file via its URL. I'd like it to be downloadable only if the role matches the one for the page display.

Any suggestion on how I should do it, or where to start looking ?

Comment: Move the file outside of the web root, and then send it to the user using `readfile()`, if they meet the security requirements to download the file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the file outside of the public directory so it's not accessible via a URL. In the controller if a user has the correct permissions then allow the user to download the file.

You could use this in your controller:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type'     => 'application/pdf',
                 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="file1.pdf"');

return new Response(file_get_contents($file), 200, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks I also thought of that implementation a few hours after posting the question.Thanks anyway it sure is the best way to do it !

Comment: One improvement to the code above would be to use the StreamedResponse to output the content as part of the body SF 2.1 only: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response

Comment: you should always stream it, because with the code above your webserver needs to have as much memory as the file size of $file